# select nth-of-type with the html markup order

Tags: css

The html markup may vary as in the following example `.menu` is illustrated:

```
<div id="main">
  <div></div>
  <div class="menu"></div>
  <div class="menu"></div>
</div>
```

for this I could use `.menu:last-child` but if this is like this:

```
<div id="main">
  <div></div>
  <div class="menu"></div>
  <div>
    <div class="menu"></div> <!--- selecting this----->
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, say like this:

```
<div id="main">
  <div></div>
  <div class="menu"></div> <!-- count as 1--->
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="menu"></div> <!--- selecting this-----> <!-- count as 2 ---->
      <div class="menu"></div> <!-- count as 3---->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, I want to target the `.menu` whether it is parent, children or siblings anything but lastly marked up html or say like nth-of-type. Is there any idea for this?

---

I mean I want as the type of the class name.

Comment: It's a little unclear what exactly you're asking.

Comment: Just say , I want to select lastly defined .menu

Comment: @C-link in that case :last-child works fine

Comment: U should have to clean your styling or add other attributes of html rather than add extra div's

Comment: please see the edited question. In the last example I want to select. How could I select that?

Comment: @KhizerNajeeb I know about that. But in my case I couldn't do that.

Comment: @C-link So, the HTML is dynamic? I thought you wanted to select the last element of type. In that last example, it is the first child.

Comment: @C-link your need is really not clear enough from the qstn. Pls modify to help the readers attempt an answer.

Comment: @JoshC Very true. What he says is unclear.

Comment: @C-link Do u want to select the 2nd element with `class="menu"` in this particular example?

Comment: @RajeshPaul yeah! you are right in that example.

Answer (score 0):

The nth-of-type will give you the nth sibling of the same type as the selected element.

This should be used when you are dealing with different element types in the same parent, and you want to select the 1st/last or nth element of a specific type only.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't any such **`pseudo-class`** to select a specific element(At a particular position) in the sequence of the elements ***with the same type*** in the context of the whole **BODY** of the document. Hence in this particular set of examples you cannot select the **2nd** of all the elements with the same specification i.e. in this case **with `class=menu`** in the context of the **whole document** but it is possible with all such elements under ***a single level of the object hierarchy of the* DOM tree** i.e. ***under a single parent***.

So the only way is through JS:

### Code

```
<script>
    onload=function()
    {
        obj=document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[1];//index=1 to access the 2nd object
        /*
         Do something with 'obj'
        */
    }
</script>
```